# Selenium - send_keys() sending incomplete string

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver

**My problem:** I have a method to fill a field, but the problem is that selenium is not sending the complete string to the field, so my assert fails at the time of verification.

**My code:**

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
var casual = require('casual');
var expect = require('chai').expect;
var By = webdriver.By;

exports.addPropuesta = function (driver) {

var first_name = casual.first_name;

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Añadir Propuesta Test')]")).click();

name_field = driver.findElement(By.name('nombre'));
name_field.sendKeys(first_name);

driver.findElement(By.css("Input[type='submit']")).click();

driver.findElement(By.css('.table')).getText().then(function(table_content){

    expect(table_content).to.include(first_name);

    });
};
```

Answer (score 8):

It looks like [this](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/10450/selenium-sendkeys-not-completing-data-entry-before-moving-to-next-field) is a common issue.

Before trying the workarounds, as a sanity check, make sure that the input field is ready to receive input by the time you are sending keys. You could also try clearing the field before calling SendKeys. I am assuming that you are seeing your string truncated, and not characters missing or being prefixed with some artifact (like placeholder text or leftover input from a previous test).

Some workarounds if that didn't work:

1. Set the value of the input field using JavaScript, instead of calling SetKeys. On some websites where I do this, the input value actually won't be recognized unless I also trigger an input changed event.

   Example in C#. Hopefully, the only change you need is to make ExecuteScript be executeScript instead.

   ```
   driver.ExecuteScript("var exampleInput = document.getElementById('exampleInput'); exampleInput.value = '" + testInputValue + "'; exampleInput.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));");
   ```

   You could, of course, split this up into two lines, one to set the value, and the second to dispatch the event.
2. Send each key individually. This is a workaround I've seen a couple of times from the threads about this issue.

   ```
   for (var i = 0; i < first_name.length; i++) {
       name_field.sendKeys(first_name.charAt(i));
   }
   ```

https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/3196
https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/2019
etc. etc. More threads can be found by a simple search of "webdriver sendkeys does not wait for all the keys" if you want to look for other possible solutions to your issue.

Comment: I tried with executeScript but occurs the same problem.

Comment: The second option works properly, but the typing is obviously too slow...

Answer (score 2):

I had run into this in a previous version and filed a bug report. It had since been fixed, but perhaps it is broken again?  In any case, when we discussed this on the [protractor chat channel](https://gitter.im/angular/protractor), the following suggestion was made: Use sendKeys as normal, then verify the result. If the result fails the sanity check, then enter the characters one at a time.

```
/**
 * A Typescript version that can be used as a mixin.
 * Make some minor modifications to use as a class.
 * @param data {string} The string to enter in the input element
 */
export class SendKeys {
    inputEl: ElementFinder;

    sendKeys(data: string) {
        var el = this.inputEl;
        // click on the input before sending data. This helps the focus and action situations.
        el.click();

        el.clear();
        el.sendKeys(data);

        // Verify whether or not hte whole data value was sent.
        // If not, send data one character at a time, which works.
        // See: https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/3196
        el.getAttribute('value').then(function (insertedValue) {
            if (insertedValue !== data) {
                // Failed, must send characters one at a time
                el.clear();
                for (let i=0; i < data.lenght; i++) {
                    el.sendKeys(data.charAt(i));
               }
           }
       });
    }
}
```

--

```
/**
 * The Javascript version:
 * @param el {ElementFinder} The input element reference
 * @param data {string} The string to enter in the input element
 */
export function sendKeys(el, data) {
        var el = this.inputEl;
        // click on the input before sending data. This helps the focus and action situations.
        el.click();

        el.clear();
        el.sendKeys(data);

        // Verify whether or not hte whole data value was sent.
        // If not, send data one character at a time, which works.
        // See: https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/3196
        el.getAttribute('value').then(function (insertedValue) {
            if (insertedValue !== data) {
                // Failed, must send characters one at a time
                el.clear();
                for (let i=0; i < data.lenght; i++) {
                    el.sendKeys(data.charAt(i));
               }
           }
       });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having this problem also, this workaround helped me.

1. Copy the whole text (that needs to be sent) to clipboard (using python "clipboard" library).
2. Activate the field on the webpage and send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 'v')

   ```
    import clipboard
    my_text = "text_to_be_sent"
    clipboard.copy(my_text)
    fld = brw.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'blah blah blah')]")
    fld.click()
    sleep(4)
    fld.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 'v')
   ```

Answer (score -2):

My resolution for this problem was add `driver.sleep(1)` before each `send_keys`

**Example:**

```
driver.sleep(1000);
driver.findElement(By.name('rut')).sendKeys(rut_text);

driver.findElement(By.name('dv')).sendKeys(dv);

driver.sleep(1000);
driver.findElement(By.name('nombre')).sendKeys(first_name);

driver.sleep(1000);
driver.findElement(By.name('apellido_paterno')).sendKeys(apellido_paterno_field);

driver.sleep(1000);
driver.findElement(By.name('apellido_materno')).sendKeys(apellido_materno);

driver.sleep(1000);
driver.findElement(By.name('celular')).sendKeys(phone_number);

driver.sleep(1000);
driver.findElement(By.name('email')).sendKeys(email);
```

I tried solve adding `execute_script` and `clear` but not solved for me.