# Sometimes not sending full text to input as expected by sendkeys in selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, webdriverwait

I try to login a site automatically by selenium.
My script sometimes works smoothly but sometimes it does not send full-text of user name or passwork to relavant inputs so it then failed to login.
I try to insert implicitly_wait but it appears  not to solve this problem totally.
I wonder if there is any function to require the webdriver to fullfill each of input before excecute another one in selenium.
Here is may attempt:

```py
browserdriver.get(url)

#fill username
browserdriver.implicitly_wait(25)
psusername=browserdriver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='form-group'][1]/input[@name='username']")
psusername.click()
psusername.send_keys("1234567890")

#fill password
browserdriver.implicitly_wait(25)
pspass=browserdriver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='form-group'][2]/input[@name='password']")
pspass.click()
pspass.send_keys("abcdefgfk12345")

browserdriver.implicitly_wait(25)
pssubmit=browserdriver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='login-btn']/button[@type='submit']")
pssubmit.click()
```

Pls, explain for me why I get stuck on this problem and how to solve it! thanks alot

EDIT1: I add the target site address: [click here](https://ban.sendo.vn/) You should click on login words (Đăng nhập) on the top right screen to see the popup login pannel.

EDIT 2: Thank to guide of below comments, I try to add some code lines to force it to key individual letter and it appears to work well so I add solution here:

```
text_input="1234567890"
for i in text_input:
    psusername.send_keys(i)
```

Comment: Try waiting that each element is clickable before clicking it. Other than that it's hard to solve without seeing the page

Comment: Could you explain more about that! If possible, pls put your guide in the answer part of this question. I tried to edit my code to fill the user name as this: psusername=WebDriverWait(browserdriver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@class='form-group'][1]/input[@name='username']")
psusername.click()
psusername.send_keys("0938866209")

Comment: But it does not work, the program showed that I got syntax error at the line: psusername.send_keys. I also tried  other as: presence_of_element_located. But it does not have any better result

Comment: site address:https://ban.sendo.vn/ You should click on words "Đăng nhập" (mean login in English) on the top right of your screen to see the pop-up login panel

Comment: Then maybe you just need to add the "login" click in the beginning of your code?

Comment: I did it in my full script. As I mentioned in my question, my problem is that my script "sometimes" does not send full text in username field. For example: just "123" instead of "1234567890". And of course, sometimes, it works perfectly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium - send\_keys() sending incomplete string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40985765/selenium-send-keys-sending-incomplete-string)

Comment: Thanks for your guide!. I read some it before posting this question. I want to find solution for python not java. I do not have coding background and python is my first language practice to find solution for  my biz's requirement.

Comment: I want to add that the above code lines work perfectly when applying for other cases (other sites)  but failed in this case so I am so curious about it

Comment: Thank you so much, keying individual letter works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use set attribute instead of sendkeys
here is the example code:

```
webdriver.executeScript("document.getElementById('elementID').setAttribute('value', '1234567890')");
```