# Trying to login to a website using selenium python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, internet-explorer

I am trying to login to a website using selenium python, the browser is Internet Explorer and yes the website only works properly in internet explorer.

I have written the below code to enter the username:

```
uname = driver.find_element(By.ID, "UserName").send_keys("RParihar")
```

When I run the code it should enter "**RParihar**" in the username field but, it is entering "**rParihar**" instead.

[image]

I have tried using the following line of codes:

```
uname = driver.find_element(By.ID, "UserName").send_keys("RParihar")
```

And

```
uname = driver.find_element(By.ID, "UserName")
uname.send_keys("RParihar")
```

And also,

```
uname = driver.find_element("id", "UserName")
uname.send_keys("RParihar")
```

I have also tried using the XPATH locator strategy.

```
uname = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id="UserName"]")
uname.send_keys("RParihar")
```

Still it is entering "**rParihar**" instead of "**RParihar**"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using JS to enter test and see if it works:

```
driver.execute_script("return document.getElementById('UserName').value='RParihar'")
```

Or try the below code if that works:

```
driver.find_element(By.ID, "UserName").clear()
driver.find_element(By.ID, "UserName").click()
driver.find_element(By.ID, "UserName").send_keys("RParihar")
```

Comment: Thanks the 2nd line of codes worked. Can you explain what was happening or what is happening after using these line of codes: `driver.find_element(By.ID, "UserName").clear()
driver.find_element(By.ID, "UserName").click()
driver.find_element(By.ID, "UserName").send_keys("RParihar")`

Comment: To be honest, I may not be able to tell the root cause of this strange behaviour. It could be a latency issue. Webpage is too slow to load and your scripts are too quick to execute. One way is you can wait until the page is completely loaded and then perform 'send_keys()'. Or the solution in this answer which worked for you, i.e. first clear(erase any value from) the username field, perform a click, then enter your username. Check this link for discussion on similar issue - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40985765/selenium-send-keys-sending-incomplete-string

Comment: And this - https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/10450/selenium-sendkeys-not-completing-data-entry-before-moving-to-next-field

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.find_element(By.ID, "UserName").click()
uname = driver.find_element(By.ID, "UserName")
uname.send_keys("R")
```

maybe work this code but i am not sure